# DATEADD - How do i make comparisons

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, compare, relational, dateadd

I am trying to check if the second attempt(u can imagine anything like password attempt, download attempt etc) is made within a time limit(`@window`) starting from attempt1 time(`@start`). Why does this report a Syntax error when other datetime comparisons work with relational operators

```
declare @start datetime
declare @window INT
select @start = GETDATE(),@window = 10

select CAST((DATEADD(MINUTE,@window,@start) <= @start) as BIT)
```

Expected output was something like 0 but i get `Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(MINUTE,@window,@start) <= @start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Could you explain why the Sql Serevr Management Studio complained about the syntax error. When something like `Select Blah blah blah from FOO where DATETIME <[>,<=,>=] ANOTHER DATETIME` works

Comment: I guess it's because SQL is not as versatile as a "normal" programming language, and logical operators (<,>,<=,>=,=) in explicit form can only be used for filtering (in WHERE clause). You just need to remember that in such cases in the SELECT statement you need to use a CASE operator

Answer (score 0):

```
select CAST((CASE 
                WHEN DATEADD(MINUTE,@window,@start) <= @start
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
        END) AS BIT)
```